# Access claims in client MVC (token based auth)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I have token based authentication on WebApi. Token with claims are send to MVC client. Claims are registered like this in WebApi

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("userName", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);
    }
```

I checked the claims and they are registered in web Api, but when MVC request the token, claims are missing.
This is happening in clinet MVC app:

```
var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var cl2 = ctx.Authentication.User.Claims; // here there is no claims
```

The same code returns correct claims in WebApi(the server)
I guess I am doing something wrong